# Can gedit split view to compare code like Notepad?

Tags: software-recommendation, gedit

I have written two file.m, I want to compare it, in Notepad, I can use a split view in the same window.

Comment: You mean [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), don’t you? And if you want to compare files in GNOME GUI, I recommend [Meld](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/meld).

Comment: ... and if you want an editor more similar to notepad++, you should try geany :-)

Comment: well, ctrl+alt+N can works! amazing!